# Make a bootable Mac OS USB which also can be read on Windows without extra software

Tags: windows-7, macos, usb, partitioning, guid

Now I have a 16GB USB stick formatted with GUID with two partitions.

The first partitions is made as Mac OS installtion disc which can be booted and install mac os properly.

For the second partition I format it (also with DiskUtility) in FAT format.

Initially I thought I can use the USB also on Windows to exchange files.

However it wont work (on Win7)

The question..
is there any possbility that I have such Mac bootable USB which has a FAT partition shared with Windows?

Comment: Does Windows recognise the USB drive at all? Does it see 2 partitions?

Comment: yes, Windows recognizes partitions but show as RAW format.